# How Can I retain session information once a user registers (Django)?

Tags: django, session, signals, registration, django-1.4

When a new user is created, I want to retain some of the information in their session

e.g. things a user has stored in their session I want to use once they have registered (or logged in).

I would use either a post_save signal on the user model (or an auth login signal), but it appears that the signals don't put the request, or session into the signal sent. It also seems I can't easily get the session from just the user.

I'm using Django 1.4

Edit: let me give an example.

The problem boils down to this - I may want to retain information for a user's activities before they login, but where do I store this information before they login? A good place would be a session (or I could link the data held in a db *to* the session, using the session a little like a makeshift user).

In any case, until they login, I can simply use their session like a user credential, and store information that persists so long as their cookie does (how else can could I reliably track an anonymous user?).

But once they register (or log-in), I want to move that information from the session, into the account properly. One good reason is that it would make sense to delete data from anonymous users periodically, whereas registered user's data would be persisted.

To do this I simply want access to the session (could be via the request) from a handler to the new-user signal, so I can make a one-off transfer from data in the session. But the new-user signal doesn't hold the session (or request).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `django.contrib.sessions` and `django.contrib.auth` for the job, the session data should be retained automatically after [login](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L74).

Moreover, the `user_logged_in` signal is sent along with request actually.

Edit:

So use `user_logged_in` signal. It carries request. Pick some specific key to store unauthenticated user's data (e.g. `"_anonymous_data"`). If that key is set on `request.session` while handeling signal, simply rewrite data on `request.user.get_profile()` object, call `save` and `del request.session["_anonymous_data"]`.

The code to retreive it could look something like:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    user_data = request.user.get_profile()
else:
    user_data = requerst.session["_anonymous_data"]
```

It's only a scratch of course. You don't want to hardcode session keys or write such logic in views. If you need it application wide, embed it in some abstraction class which takes request in `__init__`.

Comment: The session data is retained, but I want to make use of it. Is the request sent with the logged-in signal? I admit, I've only tried the new-user signal sofar.

Comment: Hmm, My app doesn't actually login the user on registraation (as would be normal), but I suppose I can call the user_login signal anyway...

Answer (score -1):

you could try using sessions:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/?from=olddocs